# I want to send values from JS to Rails when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

### Issue

When the page loaded, after adding the query parameter to the URL, I redirected to that URL.

However, an infinite loop occurs.

How can I implement this so that when the page is loaded, the value is sent from the JS to Rails and does not cause an infinite loop?

### Code

```js
window.onload = () => {
  function successGetPosition(position) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('latitude', position.coords.latitude);
    sessionStorage.setItem('longitude', position.coords.longitude);
    
    window.location.href = `/?latitude=${sessionStorage.getItem('latitude')}&longitude=${sessionStorage.getItem('longitude')}`;
  }

  function failGetPosition(error) {
        ...
  }

  options = {enableHighAccuracy: true};

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successGetPosition, failGetPosition, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
    } else { 
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
 
  getLocation();
};
```

Comment: Check if the current URL already contains `latitude` / `longitude` parameters first? Or use AJAX, instead of reloading the whole page?

Comment: @CBroe I have not checked and I'm not using Ajax. But if they are needed, please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside this function, the first thing you should do is check if the url contains latitude, longitude query params in it.

```js
function successGetPosition(position) {
    // parse the url looking for latitude and longitude params
    // if they are there, return immediately else proceed with the code below
    const [latitude, longitude] = myUrlParseFn();
    if (latitude && longitude) return;
    sessionStorage.setItem('latitude', position.coords.latitude);
    sessionStorage.setItem('longitude', position.coords.longitude);
    
    window.location.href = `/?latitude=${sessionStorage.getItem('latitude')}&longitude=${sessionStorage.getItem('longitude')}`;
  }
```